# Documents-terms matrix dimensionality reduction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I am working with text documents clustering, with a Hierarchical Clustering approach, in Python.

I have a corpus of 10k documents and have constructed a documents-terms matrix over a dictionary based on a collection of terms classified as 'keyword' for the entire corpus.
The matrix has a shape: [10000 x 2000] and is very sparse. (let's call it **dtm**)

```
id    0    1    2    4    ...    1998    1999
 0    0    0    0    1    ...       0       0
 1    0    1    0    0    ...       0       1
 2    1    0    0    0    ...       1       0
 ..    ..      ...        ...      ..      ..
9999  0    0    0    0    ...       0       0
```

I think that applying some dimensionality reduction techniques could lead to an enhancement in the precision of clustering.
I have tried using some MDS approach like this

```
def select_n_components(var_ratio, goal_var: float) -> int:
# Set initial variance explained so far
total_variance = 0.0

# Set initial number of features
n_components = 0

# For the explained variance of each feature:
for explained_variance in var_ratio:

    # Add the explained variance to the total
    total_variance += explained_variance

    # Add one to the number of components
    n_components += 1

    # If we reach our goal level of explained variance
    if total_variance >= goal_var:
        # End the loop
        break

# Return the number of components
return n_components


def do_MDS(dtm):
    # scale dtm in range [0:1] to better variance maximization
    scl = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=[0, 1])
    data_rescaled = scl.fit_transform(dtm)

    tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=data_rescaled.shape[1] - 1)
    X_tsvd = tsvd.fit(data_rescaled)

    # List of explained variances
    tsvd_var_ratios = tsvd.explained_variance_ratio_

    optimal_components = select_n_components(tsvd_var_ratios, 0.95)

    from sklearn.manifold import MDS
    mds = MDS(n_components=optimal_components, dissimilarity="euclidean", random_state=1)
    pos = mds.fit_transform(dtm.values)

    U_df = pd.DataFrame(pos)
    U_df_transposed = U_df.T  # for consistency with pipeline workflow, export tdm matrix
    return U_df_transposed
```

The objective is to automatically detect an optimal number of components and apply the dimensionality reduction. But the output has not shown a tangible enhancement.

Comment: The idea to "enhance precision of clustering by dimensionality reduction" does not seem right. It certainly not a mainstream. A commonly accepted method of text digitization is `word2vec` word embeddings and similar methods. And even after that, it is not clustering, but [LDA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#latentdirichletallocation) that is used to find structure in text data.

Comment: So a "Good idea" would be following this workflow?

Comment: (Sorry for double message) tf-if Matrix and SVD over this Matrix and then running LDA or even clustering?

Comment: I would advise you to consider `word2vec` to start with. Its benefits are twofold. First, it will return low dimension dense vectors for your words. Second, similar in context words will have similar embeddings. On top of that you're free to either cluster your docs or do LDA.

Comment: Ok, nice . I Will surely make some attempts working on that